# Summation and Patterns Question

Tags: summation, fractions

I have a really urgent question.
Today i was looking at this Pattern (Using fractions) : $\frac{1}{1*3}+\frac{1}{3*5}+\frac{1}{5*7}+\frac{1}{7*9}+...$=?
The pattern is $\frac{n}{2n+1}$.
I was wondering if you could do a summation formula, in which the end term is infinite.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just let $n \to \infty$. What do you get?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** This is a telescoping series. The general term is $\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n-1}) \cdots$$

I think you can continue after that

Comment: Please, i can't go on, can you please continue?

Comment: @RiccardoPerego: Try looking up [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).